# If V=IR Why are voltage and current interchangeable through a constant resistance

Tags: voltage, amperage, ohms-law

I hear people say things like "I only put 5 amps through the circuit but I put a bunch of volts".  I don't understand how this is possible if V=IR.  Lets say you have a circuit with 5 ohms of resistance so V=I(5).  The amount of voltage and current I am allowed to put through it has to be proportional.

Can anyone can give a good intuitive answer (don't go too in depth with math) that is understandable?

Comment: Transformers don't "just" exchange volts and amps.

Comment: Everything obeys **Maxwell's equations**, but these require calculus and vector math and are pretty complicated. So we use a simpler model called **lumped constant** where we assume resistors, voltage sources, etc. connected by ideal wires. For **DC** or steady-state circuits we also assume the voltage and currents are constant. This is where we use Ohm's law and KVL and KCL. But **transformers don't work at DC**, they require alternating current. AC analysis is more complicated; energy is still conserved but peak voltage and peak current may happen at different times.

Comment: There are all kinds of circuits that are not resistors. Ohm's Law only applies to resistors and resistances.

Comment: So are voltage and amperage always proportional in a DC circuit with resistance?

Comment: Voltage and current are always in the ratio of the resistance. If the resistance changes, then the ratio changes. There are devices with variable resistance - any wire for instance has a slight temperature coefficient of resistance - though thermistors have a much much greater variation.

Comment: Ohm's law (V=IR) is only true for purely resistive elements of a circuit. There are many electrical components that are not ohmic in nature and do not obey ohm's law.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you re-read your question, then it sort of answer's itself.  Yes...in a pure DC circuit, Ohms Law is King, and so V=I*R.  But you stated they said "I only put 5 Amps through the Circuit....so if they put a constant 5 Amps through the circuit, then the voltage will be the current times the resistance.  Since they didn't state the Resistance, then the value of the Voltage may be a "bunch of Volts"....if the resistance is high enough.  Simply put....under normal everyday simple DC circuits....most people drive them with either a Voltage or Current Source...but typically not both. If they drive the circuit with a Current, then they will see the Voltage go up proportionally.  So I believe maybe they didn't mean they "Put In" both Current and Voltage, but they put in Current and Measured a Bunch of Voltage...or Vice Versa.

Comment: I think I understand,  I probably sound like an idiot but I love to understand things intuitively. Thanks for answering guys!